# TextField Keyboard doesnt dismisses

Tags: iphone, xcode, toolbar, textfield

I am working with an app in xcode. Am stuck in a problem.  I have made a table View and made a cell where i want to display 3 textFields and Labels.  I have done it through coding and assigned textFields with tags. 
TextFields Keyboard is NumPad so for that i added a toolbar for dismissing the keyboard. toolbar have 2 buttons one cancel and one done. When i tap cancel button it dosent work for all textFields except the last textField.

Kindly help me.

Here is my code.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {


        mainTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, (80 + (i * 60)),               280, 30)];        
        mainTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        mainTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
        mainTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0]; 
        mainTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 
        mainTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;   
        mainTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        mainTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
        mainTextField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
        mainTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;  
        mainTextField.tag= i+1;
        mainTextField.delegate=self;

           [self.mainTableView  addSubview:mainTextField];

           self. numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
           self. numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
           self. numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                   [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel"   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelNumberPad)],
                                   [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                                   [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneWithNumberPad)],
                                   nil];
           [self.numberToolbar setTag:i+1];
            [self.numberToolbar sizeToFit];

            mainTextField.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;


            mainTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;

        mainLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 55+(i*60), 280, 18)];
        mainLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        mainLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        mainLabel.tag= i+1;

        {
            mainLabel.text = [passedValue objectAtIndex:[mainLabel tag]-1];             

        [self.mainTableView addSubview:mainLabel];
        [self configureView];

} 
    } 

   -(void)cancelNumberPad{

    switch ([self.numberToolbar tag]) {
        case 1:
            [mainTextField resignFirstResponder];
            break;
        case 2:
            [mainTextField resignFirstResponder];
            break;
        case 3:
            [mainTextField resignFirstResponder];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    mainTextField.text = @"";
}



-(void)doneWithNumberPad {

        NSString *numberFromTheKeyboard = mainTextField.text;
        [mainTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
```

Comment: Does the cancelNumberPad method get called when you touch cancel button?

Comment: Yeah its called. But the control goes to case 3 in switch statement. that is the last text field and cancel button works there.  however it dosent work for first two text fields

Comment: use code for Delegate like [txtfieldStreet setDelegate:self];

Comment: @JackSparrow self.myTextField.delegate = self and [self.myTextfield setDelegate:self] are identical statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way whould be to go through all of the view's subviews, check if it is a UITextField, and if it is, dissmiss it. Something like

```
-(void)myToolbarAction
{
for(int i=0;i<self.view.subviews.count; i++)
{
if([[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]
    [[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:i] resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

When you hit the cancel button you call [self.numberToolbar tag], the tag is always 3!  You have a property for the toolbar called self.numberToolbar, that property only holds a reference to one toolbar.

```
// This loop runs three times, and it just changes the tag of the self.numberToolbar.
// self.numberToolbar is only 1 toolbar and you just keep changing it's tag, the loop stops at
// 2 so the tag is 2 + 1, which is 3.
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    [self.numberToolbar setTag:i+1];
}
```

Instead just create a property or instance variable for each text field.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *textFieldOne;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *textFieldTwo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *textFieldThree;
```

Now you have a reference to each text field, now there is no need to set the tag property.  You only need on toolbar, just add it to a view and display it above the keyboard when it's called.

When the cancel button is hit, just resign all text fields, it does not matter if that text field is currently being used or not.

I find properties or instance variables much cleaner and easier then setting the tag properties.